# As a Canadian citizen working in US, can I claim my Canadian university tuition tax credit in US?

Tags: credit, tuition

I'm a Canadian citizen and started working in US on TN visa since November 2013. I have a fairly large amount of tuition credits from my graduate studies in Canada. Now, that I have my first job (after my graduation) in US, I am wondering if I can claim those tuition credits from US? I would really appreciate your advice on that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since you're a non-resident alien you cannot claim it. Had you been resident when you paid that tuition, you might have been able to claim it. You're only a US resident for tax purposes starting of the first day of your TN status, and since you don't pay US taxes on your earnings before that - you also don't get credits.

You should, of course, verify this with a licensed tax adviser (which I'm not).